# Let $G$ be a simple $2$-regular graph of order $8$. From this information you can conclude that:

Tags: graph-theory

I'm working in the following graph theory excercise:

> Let $G$ be a simple $2$-regular graph of order $8$. From this information you can conclude that:
>
> a. $G$ is semi-eulerian
>
> b. $G$ is a graph of size $8$
>
> c. $G$ is a eulerian graph
>
> d. $G$ is a bipartite graph

I'm pretty sure both $b$ and $c$ are correct but I can only choose one option so I'm confused now, thanks in advance for any correction or help.

Comment: Please show your reasoning. How did you figure that *b* and *c* are correct? We can't tell you what you did wrong if we don't know what you did! Or do you just want to know what the right answer is? It's *b*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$G$ doesn't have to be eulerian because it doesn't have to be connected.  Consider two disconnected squares.

Comment: Better yet consider $G=C_3+C_5$, the three wrong answers all fail at once.